# Forcing the order of implicit rule/pattern rule evaluation in GNU Make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a domain specific language compiler (homemade) which takes a file `x.inflow` and generates two files: `x.c` and `x.h`. The C file is compiled in the conventional manner and the generated header file has to be included into any file that calls the functions defined within it.

The header files therefore have to be generated before any C files that use them are compiled. My current Makefile, below, works fine except for the first build from clean where it can try and compile `main.c` before the header file that it includes has been created.

```
NAME = simplest

OBJ = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard *.c)) \
        $(patsubst %.inflow,%.o,$(wildcard *.inflow))

CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -Wall

$(NAME): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(CLIBS)

# Dependencies for existing .o files.
-include $(OBJ:.o=.d)

# Compile an inflow file into both a .c and .h file.
# Note that this rule has two targets.
%.c %.h: %.inflow
    inflow $<

# Compile object files and generate dependency information.
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -MD -MP -c $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

Obviously, I can fix this for specific cases by adding, for example (where `simplest.h` is a generated header):

```
main.o: simplest.h
```

But is there a general way to force one type of pattern rule (`%.c %.h: %.inflow`) to be run before any invokations of another (`%.o: %.c`)?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can force any target to be run before any other target with *order-only prerequisites*.  So for example, you can write:

```
%.o : %.c | simplest.h
        $(CC) -MD -MP -c $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

which will ensure that no target that uses this pattern rule to build will be invoked before the target `simplest.h` is created.  However, I don't think you can put patterns in an order-only prerequisite.  To be honest, I've never tried it so it's possible that it works, I'm not sure.

If not, you could just list *all* the order-only prerequisites in the `%.o` pattern rule; this would ensure that all the inflow files are generated before *any* of the object files are built.  That's probably OK.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is twofold:

1. Make doesn't know that it needs to generate `simplest.h` before compiling `main.c`.
2. You don't want to have to explicitly tell Make about the dependency (and remember to update it when it changes).

Rather than force Make to evaluate rules in a set order, you can solve your problem by letting Make create the dependencies for you.  Check out this section of the Gnu Make manual:  http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Prerequisites

When you run Make, it will scan your source files and gather their dependencies for you (and you won't have to explicitly list that `main.o` depends on `simplest.h`).